# PySide IPC with signals/slots

Tags: python, qt, ipc, dbus, pyside

I've been trying to figure out if there's any way to manage IPC in PySide and still take advantage of Qt's signals/slots mechanism. The QtDBus module sounds great, but it doesn't appear to be available in PySide. I came across https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_DBus_Integration on the Qt wiki - but that doesn't seem to get me there.

Any IPC framework supporting signals/slots would really make my day. Has anyone else had this problem - what was the final verdict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic IPC solutions [[source]](http://weber.fi.eu.org/teaching/TIES425/lectures/):

---

- Pipes
- Sockets (sockets, ZMQ)
- System V IPC, like shared memory, message queue, semaphore, ([DBus](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_DBus_Integration))

IPython uses ZMQ to solve similar problems. 
Here is some nice documentation about that: [IPython QT interface](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.2/development/ipython_qt.html)